# Get PullRequest Number From Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I am trying to setup Sonarcloud within a Gradle job.  Can someone point me to the right way to get the last pull request from the current branch within Gradle?

I need it for the key property.

Comment: Do you need the latest pull request or the latest branch merge?

Comment: @cyroxis I need the latest pull request number to use as the sonar key property

Comment: @1tSurge I also exactly needed the same. Could you please let me know if you have resolved this?.